# Get active panel in a jquery accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, knockout.js

I´m struggling with getting the active panel in a jquery accordion.

Given the equivalent of a select-element:

```
<select data-bind="options: Tasks, optionsText: 'TaskName', value: SelectedTask"></select>
```

where Tasks = ko.observableArray(); initialized by a db-call.

What I want to achieve is to set SelectedTask to the chose panel in my jQuery UI accordion.

My accordion in created by a knockout-loop:

```
<div id="accordion" data-bind="jqAccordion: { },template: { name: 'scene-template', foreach: Scenes, afterAdd: function(elem){$(elem).trigger('valueChanged');} }"></div>      

<script type="text/html" id="scene-template">
    <div data-bind="attr: {'id': 'Scene' + SceneId}" class="group">
        <h3>
            <b><span data-bind="text: TaskId"></span>: <input name="TaskName" data-bind="value: TaskName" /></b>                
        </h3>
        <p>
            Description:<textarea name="Description" data-bind="value: Description"></textarea>
        </p>
    </div>
</script>
```

Data-binding "SelectedTask" to any of the header elements in the template fails, making me think I have to do this in the accordion code, for instance in a "click" event. I´m able to defining the click-event, but how do I set "SelectedTask" to the item that has been clicked?

Comment: I guess this must be really easy, as the ui.item.siblings().andSelf().each()-function will return all the objects, but I´m only interested in the "andSelf()" one....

Answer (score 1):

If you only care about setting the selectedTask to an accordion panel that is opening, then consider the [beforeActivate](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#event-beforeActivate) event handler on the jqAccordion.

> If the accordion is currently collapsed, ui.oldHeader and ui.oldPanel will be empty jQuery objects. If the accordion is collapsing, ui.newHeader and ui.newPanel will be empty jQuery objects.

I don't like this wording as it's kind of confusing, but basically, `$(ui.newHeader)[0]` is truthy when the panel is about to be expanded and `$(ui.oldHeader)[0]` is truthy when the panel is about to be collapsed.  And we only care about setting selected if it's about to expand (you could set selected to null if it's about to collapse but that's a preference call).

So in your CustomBinding, add this to your accordion options:

```
$(element).accordion({
    beforeActivate: function (event, ui) {
        if ($(ui.newHeader)[0]) {
            bindingContext.$root.SelectedTask(ko.contextFor($(ui.newHeader)[0]).$data);
            // I think this is equivalent to:
            // viewModel.SelectedTask(ko.contextFor($(ui.newHeader)[0]).$data);
        }
    }
});
```

Let me know if this works.  This is kind of a shot in the dark (untested), but I think it should.

Comment: Thanks again, Dennis! You make me learn a lot. :)

Basically I am only interested in setting SelectedTask when a NEW task is selected. Ideally I´d like to be able to select the Task without expanding with a single click, expand it with a double click, the collapse it with a new select (click).

Comment: As my accordion is sortable I also need to save the sequence of the Tasks (I have TaskSequenceNo = ko.observable(); to handle this.) As it is, my SelectedTask is firing when selecting new task, but also when expanding and collapsing the currently selected. It is not firing when I sort my accordion. Of course I could handle the writing of TaskSequenceNo as a batch update for all Tasks, although I think it would be more elegant to do it with the SelectedTask.

Comment: I wouldn't say 'NEW', I would say 'expanded' to avoid confusion. If a task is 'expanded', it should be selected. What should happen if it is collapsed (`$(ui.oldHeader)[0]` is truthy)? Personally I would set SelectedTask to null, but that's a business decision.

Comment: Could we agree on "Changed" ? ;)

As I´d like the possibility of NOT expanding a (by one click) selected Task. 
When collapsing I think I´d like to see SelectedTask unchanged, unless  selecting another item is causing the collapse off course.

Comment: Sorting, you're going to do the same thing you did with the accordion to set the SelectedTask.  On sortable's stop event.  Set `viewModel.SelectedTask(ko.contextFor($(ui.item)[0]).$data)`.  $(ui.item).index() will give you the new index or TaskSequenceNo.  From there you can .splice the underlying array to pull and put the SelectedTask into the right spot in the array.  At that point you would want to loop through the array and update the TaskSequenceNos with each Task's respective index. And yeah, given the sorting, I can agree on 'Changed'.

Comment: Hi again!

I´m struggling to get accordion data out of the ui.
$(ui.item).index()  gives me the sequence all right (an alert("...") proves that), but when setting "ViewModel.SelectedTask().SequenceNo($(ui.item).index());" inside the .sortable('stop') option I get an error message "SelectedTask is not a function", i.e. the accordion does not recognize my SelectedTask as a ko.observable().

Same problem with the SequenceNo; how do I get it "out" of the accordion?